# Google Maps DirectionService.Route Batching Request

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-directions-api

Is it possible to batch requests to google maps direction api?
I have multiple origin and destination that I would like to get the driving times for. (they will be displayed on a map but that is not included in this problem)

Currently I have this working:

```
 var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
 var request ={
          origin: "-27.997450,153.375488",
          destination: "-28.044420,153.346460",
          travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }
 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        console.log(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
  })
```

Ideally it would work if I made a request an array like this:

```
var request =[{
      origin: "-27.997450,153.375488",
      destination: "-28.044420,153.346460",
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    },{
      origin: "-27.997450,153.375488",
      destination: "-27.714710,153.196930",
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }]
```

but the above does not work. If I'm unable to batch I will need to make 5-10 requests which I want to prevent

Comment: What about the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start)?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @MrUpsidown, I missed that.

Distance Matrix API was what I needed